# if else: else portion not returning output

Tags: r, function, conditional-statements

I am currently trying to cycle through a dataframe of integers and characters and change one value of each row, conditionally. For all rows that do not meet the conditions I would just like to add them back into a new dataframe filled with the modified rows.

I've done this before with no trouble, but I feel as though I have been staring at this too long without any enlightenment.

```
a<-data.frame(cbind(1,'a',2,'c',3,'d'), stringsAsFactors = F)
b<-data.frame(cbind(1,'a',2,'c',3,'g'), stringsAsFactors = F)
c<-data.frame(cbind(1,'f',4,'g',5,'h'), stringsAsFactors = F)

x<-rbind(a,b,c)

fun<-function(x){
  fin<-NULL
  for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
   v<-x[i+1,]
   if ((x[i,1]== v[i,1]) & (x[i,2]==v[i,2]) ){
      x[i,3]<-"f"
      fin<-rbind(fin, x[i,])
    }else {fin<-rbind(fin, x[i,]) }
  return(fin)
  }
}
fun(x) 
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
1  1  a  f  c  3  d
>
```

The result I desire:

```
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
1  1  a  f  c  3  d
1  1  a  2  c  3  g
1  1  f  4  g  5  h
```

Comment: Your `i+1` logic will not work (return all `NA`) when `i <- nrow(x)` and it tries to access the next (non-existent) row. If you must do this in a loop (much more literal than R requires/suggests/recommends), then do `1:(nrow(x)-1)`.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for pointing out that mistake and the quick response. Makes perfect sense, I just hadn't gotten to that point in troubleshooting, as it never returned that row of NA's (or any row past the first). Changing  'for loop' to the correct syntax did not produce the additional rows I was looking for. If I change the conditional to something like '(i==2)' or '(i==3)' the function will return the first row unaltered. I am clearly missing something fundamental here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or an alternative:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

> z <- x %>% mutate(match = ifelse(( (lead(X1)==X1) & (lead(X2)==X2)),"YES","NO"))
> z %>% mutate(X3 = replace(X3, match=="YES", "f"))
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 match
1  1  a  f  c  3  d   YES
2  1  a  2  c  3  g    NO
3  1  f  4  g  5  h  <NA>
```

Comment: This is great advice, thanks. At some point I had gotten frustrated with `dplyr` and reverted to `base` functions; but given the time I've wasted , I think it's time to circle back to `dplyr`.